# Ruby rescue custom exception

Tags: ruby, exception, custom-exceptions

In following example:

```
class Foo
  class MyCustomerror < StandardError
    def message
      "My custom error"
    end
 end

 def self.do_standard
   1 / 0
 rescue StandardError => e
   puts e.message
 end

 def self.do_custom
   1 / 0
 rescue MyCustomerror => e
  puts e.message
 end
end
```

I have a problem with call rescue block which params is MyCustomerror.
If i call Foo.do_standard, rescue block is called, however when i call Foo.do_custom rescue block with  MyCustomerror isn't called. Where is the problem?

Comment: `rescue MyCustomerror` rescues `MyCustomerror` and its subclasses. But `ZeroDivisionError` isn't one of its subclasses.

Answer (score 2):

There is no place in your code that could raise a `MyCustomError` exception, so there is nothing to rescue from. The only exception that could possibly be raised by that code is a `ZeroDivisionError`.

Comment: It might be worth noting that `ZeroDivisionError` inherits from `StandardError` which is why `rescue StandardError` rescues it.

Comment: Place or not place. It does not explain why in case call method do_standard is caught by StandardError, instead  in case call do_custom not.

Comment: @Stefan In the above example MyCustomerror is also inherited by StandardError!

Comment: Both functions raise `ZeroDivisionError`.  `ZeroDivisionError` is a `StandardError` so `.do_standard` rescues it.  `ZeroDivisionError` is not a `MyCustomerror` and so `.do_custom` does not rescue it.

Comment: @user3471671 it's the other way round: `MyCustomerror` inherits from `StandardError`. In the class hierarchy, `MyCustomerror` and `ZeroDivisionError` are siblings.